# How to import CSS files in vue components with scope limited to components only?

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack

How do I import CSS files into vue components so that the scope of those files limited to components only, I tried importing the files into style tab in a single component file with the scoped property but it still bundles all the CSS and overriding one another? Is there any way I can import CSS files with scoped limited to Single file component? I don't want my CSS to be overwritten by other component CSS files? and one more thing I am using webpack cli 3. Thank you so much for your time. Will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 13):

Finally after so much googling and hits and tires i found one answer. we can do something like this in the Single File Component. this will make you CSS src file scoped to your component only. Thank you for your time!

```
<style scoped src="@/assets/css/main.css"></style>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution with bootstrap but it is not working. But when I remove the scoped attribute it is working

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I was trying include .css file from the node_modules folder.